# I need a way to get updated oauth tokens for google photos

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-photos

I'm currently working on an application for myself in which I need access to my own photos/albums on Google Photos. I have gotten by using the oauth 2.0 token generated in the playground, but I'd like to get a more permanent solution that does not require me manually regenerating the token. Is this possible with Google Cloud? The app is meant to run in daemon, so this makes any option with consent pages unusable. The scopes I'm using are:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.sharing
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly.appcreateddata
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly

I have tried using the https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token and https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth endpoints to generate one programatically, but the only minor success I had was /auth sending me to a consent screen. I've also looked at using the refresh token given by Google Oauth playground with no luck there either.

Just looking to see if there is anything that I am missing.. This is my first post on stackoverflow, so please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to make it an internal app as it was for personal use and not for an organization.

Solved this by first using the google api package to create my own access/refresh token for my oauth client, then calling the https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token endpoint each time to generate a valid access token. I hope this can be helpful to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [setup](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en) documentation, as long as your app is marked as internal, you should not need to verify the app and can use it without the consent screen.